# Updating ObservableCollection from within a ModalAsync

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an observable collection that needs to be updated from a pushed modalasync. The observable collection is basically a cart. In the main page (MyHome.xaml.cs) I have another observable collection, which when items are clicked pushes a modal async to a selctionPage(SelectionPage.xaml.cs). In this selection page I add an item to the Cart observable collection located in MyHome.xaml.

My problem is that the collection does not update when we go back and look at the cart. I have tried sending MyHomePage and the actual Cart during pushModalAsync but neither of those work. I have also tried calling MyHome functions from within the modal async and that does not work either.

**MyHome.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using HW3.ViewModel;
using HW3.Model;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace HW3.Views
{
    public partial class MyHome : ContentPage
    {

       
        public ObservableCollection<Product> Cart { get; set; }
        
        Product jello = new ProductByQuantity(1.00, 3, "Jello", "Canned & Packaged Foods", 0001);

        public MyHome()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new ProductViewModel();

            //Cart = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
            //Cart.Add(jello);
            //Cart.Add(jello);

            //add(jello);

        }

        private async void OnItemSelected(Object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            //add(e.Item as Product);
            if (e.Item is ProductByWeight)
            {
                var extra = e.Item as ProductByWeight;
                var details = e.Item as Product;

                
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SelectionPage(details.Name, details.Price, details.Description, details.ID, extra.getOunces(), extra, Cart, this));
            }
            else if(e.Item is ProductByQuantity)
            {
                var extra = e.Item as ProductByQuantity;
                var details = e.Item as Product;

                //Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new SelectionPage(details.Name, details.Price, details.Description, details.ID, extra.getUnits(), extra, Cart, this)));
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SelectionPage(details.Name, details.Price, details.Description, details.ID, extra.getUnits(), extra, Cart, this));
            }

        }

        public void add(Product p)
        {
            
            
        }

    };

}
```

**SelectionPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using HW3.Model;
using HW3.ViewModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace HW3.Views
{
    public partial class SelectionPage : ContentPage
    {

        MyCartViewModel myCartViewModel = new MyCartViewModel();
        ObservableCollection<Product> pr;
        MyHome Home;
        Product chicken = new ProductByWeight(12.50, 75, "Chicken Breast", "Produce", 0016);
        public ObservableCollection<Product> Cart1 { get; set; }

        public SelectionPage(string Name, double Price, string Description, int ID, double units_ounces, Product product, ObservableCollection<Product> p, MyHome home)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //property equal cart here

            testName.Text = product.Name;
            testPrice.Text = "Price: $" + Price.ToString();
            testInventory.Text = "Inventory: " + units_ounces.ToString();
            testDescription.Text = Description;
            slider.Minimum = 1;
            slider.Maximum = units_ounces;
            sliderNumber.Text = "Value: 1";
            pr = p;
            Home = home;
            

        }

        private void slider_changed(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var newStep = Math.Round(e.NewValue / 1.0);

            slider.Value = newStep * 1.0;
            sliderNumber.Text = "Value: " + slider.Value;
        }

        private async void addButton_clicked(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            string str = sliderNumber.Text;
            var result = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
            
            var chicken = new ProductByWeight(12.50, 75, "Chicken Breast", "Produce", 0016);

            //Home.Cart.Add(chicken);
            //Home.add(chicken);
            //pr.Add(chicken);

            Cart1 = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
            Cart1.Add(chicken);
            
            Home.Cart = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
            Home.Cart = Cart1;
            foreach(Product x in Home.Cart)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello " + x.Name);
            }

        }
        private async void backButton_clicked(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var chicken = new ProductByWeight(12.50, 75, "Chicken Breast", "Produce", 0016);
            //Home.add(chicken);
            //Home.Cart.Add(chicken);
            //pr.Add(chicken);
            Navigation.PopModalAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

**MyCart.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using HW3.Model;
using HW3.ViewModel;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace HW3.Views
{
    public partial class MyCart : ContentPage
    {
        public List<Product> myCart1 = new List<Product>();

        public MyCart()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = new MyHome();
            
        }

       
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who helps! I have been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: in `SelectionPage` you pass in a reference to the `Cart` ObservableCollection but you never do anything with it.  You should be able to add items and they will be reflected in the `MyHome` because they are referencing the same object.  There are also several places in your code where you are creating **new** objects - any time you do that you are getting a **new** copy of a class that has no connection to the copy used elsewhere in your code, and updating that **new** copy will not be reflected in other pages

Comment: How would I initialize Cart without using = new ObservaleCollection<Product>()? When I try to add from inside the selctionpage using the reference pr without initializing my program crashes, and if I do initialize  I am just creating a new copy right?

Comment: you initialize it **once** and then share that reference.  Otherwise every page will have their own independent, **empty** copy

Comment: Do I initialize it inside the constructor of MyHome? or somewhere else?

Comment: that really depends on how your app is designed and your requirements.  Home probably makes sense.  If this is going to be used throughout your app it would make sense to make Cart a property of the App class so you can share one reference throughout your app

Comment: Awesome, I'm routing everything through App so I can use it in multiple places. Thank you! I'm new here, is there a way I can thumbs ups your answer?

Comment: I added an answer below

Answer (score 0):

in `SelectionPage` you pass in a reference to the Cart `ObservableCollection` but you never do anything with it. You should be able to add items and they will be reflected in the `MyHome` because they are referencing the same object. There are also several places in your code where you are creating new objects - any time you do that you are getting a new copy of a class that has no connection to the copy used elsewhere in your code, and updating that new copy will not be reflected in other pages

a better approach would be to create `Cart` as a property on the `App` class, so that it is easily accessible from every page of your app